# how to make head of dropdown link clickable in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make the `dropdown` items appear on hover of the parent link, and to be clickable to a another page, how can this be done?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#"> <img src="assets/img/Saydullogo.png" id="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="Categories.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa fa-medkit"></span> Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cosmetics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medicines</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Registeration</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-phone-square"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Sir can you please make a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this css in your code

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
   display: block !important;
}
```

check out this snippet with your code

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#"> <img src="assets/img/Saydullogo.png" id="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="Categories.php" class="dropdown-toggle" ><span class="fa fa-medkit"></span> Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cosmetics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medicines</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Registeration</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-phone-square"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: ....The hover works fine, but the parent link is not clickable to be able to open another page.

Comment: so you want categories also clickable?

Comment: Updated please check, removed data-toggle="dropdown" in your anchr tag

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

this.girish - that code works perfectly.